# Running PHP script after 10 seconds since load time

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a website and I can not figure out one thing. I need a script that checks if 10 seconds have past since load time, then it would run another PHP script. But I am not sure if it is possible. I have attached my attempt at this problem. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
if (
<script type="text/javascript">
    function viewplus(){
    }
    setTimeout(viewplus, 10000);
</script>
)
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $rws2['id_user'];
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$rws2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$views_total = $rws2['views_total'] + 1;
$views_week = $rws2['views_week'] + 1;
$views_today = $rws2['views_today'] + 1;
$id = $rws2['id'];
$query = "UPDATE users SET views_total='$views_total',views_week='$views_week',views_today='$views_today' WHERE id='$id'";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Comment: You can't use PHP inside JavaScript. Use `ajax`

Comment: I`m using JavaScript inside PHP

Comment: You cannot do that either, one way would be to echo the javascript so that the browser can run it. javascript only runs in the browser, PHP only runs in the server

Comment: In order to 'check if 10 seconds have past since load time' you need to use ajax (execute some PHP code from Javascript)

Comment: Could you help me with the AJAX script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using jQuery like this:
Put your code in a php file and call it after 10 seconds after page load with

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Check if the page has loaded completely                                         
$(document).ready( function() { 
    setTimeout( function() { 
        $('#some_id').load('index.php'); 
    }, 10000); 
}); 
</script>
```

Example of updating a table and receiving a status message:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])&&
    isset($_POST['var'])){

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world"); 

$id = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['id1']); //In our example id is INT
$var = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['var']);
$result = $con->query("UPDATE table SET value = '$var' WHERE id = $id);
(!$result) ? echo "Update failed!" : "Update succeeded";
}
```

This will load the output of your php file(Update filed or succeeded) in a element (this case one with id  `some_id`).

Another way which I DO NOT recommend is using PHP's `sleep()` function [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: Can I pass multiple variables? such as index.php?id1=xxx&id2=yyy&id3=zzz

Comment: You can pass parameters with GET or POST. Example of passing paramtere using POST:
`$('#some_id').load('index.php', {'id1': 'value', 'id2': 'value2'});`

Comment: Note that this solution assumes you're using jQuery on the client side.

Comment: And, does this code redirect to another page or loads the data generated by the php code? Because I dont thing that this will work in my situation, because I`m updating a database.

Comment: At least you can try.

Comment: In my example it loads data from index.php and displays it in the element with id `some_id` after 10 seconds from page load. No redirection.

Comment: If I want to update a Database then I should redirect to another PHP page using window.location?